# Ubuntu 10.10 Desktop: configuring postfix to send mail as

Tags: postfix

I have been learning how to use postfix to end email using the command line, which I find helpful when at work and I don't want to open a browser or switch to mouse, to send an email about my broken stuff to system admin. I've been practicing from my laptop.

Ubuntu uses postfix, and I found the file /etc/postfix/main.cf

The default is for sent mail to be $USER@$mydomain, so at this point I have:
$USER@gmail.com  as the sender when I check my gmail account.

I can't figure out how to get another name other than $USER, such as my regular gmail name, so people can respond to my gmail account.

TIA !

wbg

Comment: update: man sendmail says I can use the flag -f which worked...

Comment: NEVER MIND...after more googling I foudn out that postfix does not allow subjects and is generally the wrong program....I installed mail-utils.